# Вывод картинки в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть список из 500 элементов. В каждом элементе слева выводится картинки в ImageView размером 160х100. Одна картинка весит около 40 КБ.

Вопрос будет ли при прокрутке лагать приложение из-за того что картинки будут подгружаться? Или стоит уменьшить размер картинок?

Comment: С размером 160х100 проблем возникнуть не должно.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ.

Comment: а откуда картинки? если они кешируются/грузятся асинхронно, то проблем вообще не будет

Comment: Картинки лежат в assets. Я просто помню что при реализации ExpandableListView были такие проблемы у меня. При быстрой прокрутке приложение падало. Решал я это уменьшением размера картинок тоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего нет.Вы реализуете паттерн ViewHolder. без него это былобы проблемно.